# How to copy file to /system/xbin from TWRP?

Tags: android, recovery, su, superuser

CM13 is running on my phone and I'd like to use an app which has root detection so I need to delete /system/xbin/su. If I just rename the file (e.g.: subak) it works until I reboot the device. After the reboot executing subak command doesn't give me a root shell. I tried to flash superSU from TWRP and ended up with a bootloop and needed to reflash the ROM. I'm wondering if it's possible to make a copy of the su binary and somehow copy it back to /system/xbin from TWRP ( xbin folder doesn't show up in the TWRP file explorer) if root access needed?

Comment: You might want to use `Enable superuser` option in SuperSU app settings to disable and hide superuser and enable it back. If it doesn't work for your root detection case, you can use `Full unroot` option to remove root and then once you're done, root again using TWRP flashing of SuperSU

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Flashing superSU from TWRP for CM13 caused bootloop and I needed to reflash the whole ROM, so unfortunately this is not an option. This solution worked fine with CM11 but not with CM13.

Comment: Actually, rooting a fresh ROM requires more than just copying the `su` binary to `/system/xbin`. If SuperSU flashable zip is not working for you, you could look at alternate recovery flashable root methods for your device / ROM. If you still want to copy only `su` binary, please check if you're mounting `system` partition from TWRP before going to the file manager - it is not mounted by default.

Comment: meanwhile i've solved the issue. mounting the system partition was definitely part of the solution :) It also turned out that the file has to be moved ("mv /system/xbin/su /system/xbin/subak" and vice versa) instead of copied otherwise normal user cannot see it in the xbin folder not even after fixing permission (chmod) and ownership. It could be some kind of SELinux thing. Anyway thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

meanwhile i've solved the issue. mounting the system partition was definitely part of the solution :) It also turned out that the file has to be moved ("mv /system/xbin/su /system/xbin/subak" and vice versa) instead of copied otherwise normal user cannot see it in the xbin folder not even after fixing permission (chmod) and ownership. It could be some kind of SELinux thing.